# OpenXR device not present in Start or Awake methods in Unity C# script

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, valve

I'm developing a VR game using OpenXR in Unity (specifically developing on a Valve Index). When I try to access the input devices through the [`InputDevices.GetDevices()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/XR.InputDevices.GetDevices.html) function, I get 0 devices back when I call this function from my script's `Awake()` or `Start()` methods. But when I call the same function from my script's `Update()` method, I see all the devices (e.g. head set, left controller, right controller).

Why can't I see the devices in the `Awake()` or `Start()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that some devices, like the Valve Index, don't initialize until you pick them up. Which can happen *after* the `Start()` method runs.

So to solve this, you need to write a function that is called later on during the `Update()` method until you have the device object(s) you need.

For example, if you want to find the left controller, you would run something like the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.PackageManager;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class HandPresence : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InputDevice _targetDevice;
    
    void Start()
    {
        TryInitialize();
    }

    void TryInitialize()
    {
        var inputDevices = new List<InputDevice>();
        InputDeviceCharacteristics rightControllerCharacteristics =
            InputDeviceCharacteristics.Right | InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller;
        InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(rightControllerCharacteristics, inputDevices);

        if (inputDevices.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        _targetDevice = inputDevices[0];
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!_targetDevice.isValid)
        {
            TryInitialize();
        }
        else
        {
            // Do what you would like with _targetDevice here
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, we use the `TryInitialize()` function to save the device into a private class variable. We run this function in the `Start()` method, but then check if we actually saved a device (by checking if the private class variable is valid) in the `Update()` method, and call `TryInitialize()` again if we did not.

This was tested and works in Unity 2020.2.7f1, with OpenXR 1.02.

Answer (score 2):

A bit better solution with Coroutine and reusable code for multiple controllers.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class HandPresence : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InputDevice _rightController;
    private InputDevice _leftController;
    
    void Start()
    {
        var characteristics = InputDeviceCharacteristics.Right | InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller;
        StartCoroutine(RepeatGetDevice(_rightController, characteristics));
        
        characteristics = InputDeviceCharacteristics.Left | InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller;
        StartCoroutine(RepeatGetDevice(_leftController, characteristics));
    }

    private IEnumerator RepeatGetDevice(InputDevice device, InputDeviceCharacteristics characteristics )
    {
        var devices = new List<InputDevice>();

        do
        {
            yield return null;
            InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(characteristics, devices);
            if (devices.Count > 0)
                device = devices[0];
        } while (devices.Count == 0);
        
        Debug.Log($"{device.name} : {device.characteristics}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional information. You could describe what parts of the code are key to the solution you provided.